# Adding and overriding files in Dokuwiki Bitnami docker image

Tags: docker, bitnami, dokuwiki

Am trying to enable 'translation' plugin dokuwiki and few other changes to Dokuwiki Bitnami image. For instance I add a new file to 'lib/tpl/dokuwiki' to Dokuwiki Bitnami image and also overriding a 'lang.php'.

Changes to default original  [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-dokuwiki/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

```
   - './conf/lang.php:/bitnami/dokuwiki/lib/tpl/dokuwiki/lang/en/lang.php'
      - './conf/sidebarheader.html:/bitnami/dokuwiki/lib/tpl/dokuwiki/sidebarheader.html'
```

However the changes are not reflected in the container and no errors are generated.. Any suggestion are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what it worked for us:

1. Install plugin with extension manager. https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:translation
2. Copy the local.php file to the host machine

```
docker cp <container>:/bitnami/dokuwiki/conf/local.php conf/local.php
```

3. Append the following to the local.php file. https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:translation#manual_configuration

```
$conf['plugin']['translation']['translations']  = 'en,fr,de,it';                        // available languages
$conf['plugin']['translation']['dropdown']      = 1;                                    // use a dropdown
$conf['plugin']['translation']['translationns'] = 'wiki';                               // namespace where to activate translation
$conf['plugin']['translation']['skiptrans']     = '^:(plugin|template):';               // what to skip (regexp)
$conf['plugin']['translation']['translateui']   = 1;                                    // translate the wiki user interface too
$conf['plugin']['translation']['checkage']      = 1;                                    // show notice on outdated translations
$conf['plugin']['translation']['about']         = 'translation:about';                  // page describing the translation process to users
$conf['plugin']['translation']['localabout']    = 1;
$conf['plugin']['translation']['display']       = 'langcode,name';
```

4. Create `conf/sidebarheader.html` in the host machine:

```
<?php
$translation = plugin_load('helper','translation');
if ($translation) echo $translation->showTranslations();
?>
```

5. Make sure the sidebar is created. Create it if not. http://<YOUR_SERVER>/doku.php?id=sidebar
6. Mount files in the docker-compose

```
    volumes:
      - 'dokuwiki_data:/bitnami'
      - './conf/local.php:/bitnami/dokuwiki/conf/local.php'
      - './conf/sidebarheader.html:/bitnami/dokuwiki/lib/tpl/dokuwiki/sidebarheader.html'
```

7. Recreate the container to apply the new mounted paths

```
dc down && dc up
```

[image]